# Is there a way of reformatting all code chunks in an Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r-markdown, formatr

Is there a way to reformat all code chunks in an Rmarkdown document?

I have Rmarkdown documents which need code reformatting but I can't select all and use the Rstudio reformat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package styler can reformat Rmarkdown files.

```
library(styler)
style_file("badlyFormattedFile.Rmd")
```

It can also reformat all Rmd or R scripts in a directory using

```
style_dir("directoryWithUglyFiles")
```